# VertexLabels not inherited by edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'd like to custom name the vertices of a (complete) graph and have those names reflected in the edges.

shiftGraph produces a complete graph with vertices labels from imin to imax.

```
             CompleteGraph[imax - imin + 1, DirectedEdges -> True, 
                           VertexLabels -> Thread[Rule[Range[1, imax - imin + 1],Range[imin, imax]]]];
```

shiftGraph[2,4] yields:

[image: Complete Graph on 2 through 4]

But those vertex labels are not inherited by the edges:

```
EdgeList[shiftGraph[2, 4]]
```

yields

{1 [DirectedEdge] 2, 1 [DirectedEdge] 3, 2 [DirectedEdge] 1,
2 [DirectedEdge] 3, 3 [DirectedEdge] 1, 3 [DirectedEdge] 2}

Is that expected or desirable? I suppose the fix is to apply the VertexLabels rules to the edges. Cleaner methods?

Comment: `VertexLabels` only affects the display of the vertices - the underlying vertex names are still 1 to n (compare also with `Graph`). Unfortunately, you can't specify the vertex names for `CompleteGraph` upon construction, so you'll have to rename them after the fact using [`VertexReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexReplace.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`IndexGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IndexGraph.html) to get the desired result:

```
ClearAll[shiftGraph]
shiftGraph[imin_, imax_, o : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
 Graph[IndexGraph[CompleteGraph[imax - imin + 1, DirectedEdges -> True], imin], o]


shiftGraph[2, 4, VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
EdgeList[shiftGraph[2, 4]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. The language is so rich, it is impossible to be familiar with all its many features.

Answer (score 1):

`IGCompleteGraph` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/) makes it easy to create a complete graph with the vertex names of your choice.

```
EdgeList@IGCompleteGraph[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}]
(* {"a" \[UndirectedEdge] "b", "a" \[UndirectedEdge] "c", 
 "a" \[UndirectedEdge] "d", "b" \[UndirectedEdge] "c", 
 "b" \[UndirectedEdge] "d", "c" \[UndirectedEdge] "d"} *)
```